# Creating a TEMP stored procedure in Informix

Tags: informix

How to create a Temp stored procedure in Informix. I think there is way to do this in SQL Server, by adding '#' at the beginning of the name. I couldn't find anything similar for Informix.

Answer (score 2):

Informix doesn't provide a way to create a stored procedure that is formally designated as 'temporary' — that will go away when the session ends.  All stored procedures are 'permanent', though there's nothing to stop you deleting what you created with seconds of creating it.